# Why doesn't the [NOT IN ] syntax work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to execute the following query but it doesn't get any data although it should get one row :

```
select * from [DB1.table1] where col1 not in (select col2 from DB2.table2)
```

col1,col2 are of type varchar

why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Type of col1 = col2? Collation?

Comment: It will return no rows if `col2` is nullable and it *is* `NULL` for one of the rows - but you've not given us enough information to know if this is the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Doesn't work*" isn't exactly a good description of your problem, but in nearly all cases this is caused by the sub-select returning NULL values.

You probably want this:

```
select * from [DB1.table1] 
where col1 not in (select col2 from DB2.table2 where col2 is not null);
```

The comparison with `NULL` always yield "undefined" and thus if at least one row from the sub-select contains a `NULL` in the `col2` column the whole expression is "undefined". As undefined not "true", the whole query doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `NULL`s in `col2` in `table2`, you'll get the behaviour you describe:

```
create table table2 (
    col2 varchar(10) null
)
insert into table2 (col2) values ('abc'),(null)
create table table1 (
    col1 varchar(10) null
)
insert into table1 (col1) values ('abc'),('def')

select * from table1 where col1 not in (select col2 from table2)
```

Produces no rows. This is because the result of `NOT IN` becomes `UNKNOWN` once a `NULL` comparison occurs.

You can fix it with:

```
select * from table1 where col1 not in (select col2 from table2 where col2 is not null)
```

If that's the correct logic for your situtation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed to the reason that cause this issue, you can achieve the same results, using `LEFT JOIN` and it safe than the predicate `IN` with the `NULL` vlaues:

```
select t1.* 
from [DB1.table1] AS T1 
LEFT JOIN  DB2.table2 AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
where t1.col2 IS NULL;
```